# Get list of files using glob in command mode

Tags: key-bindings, command-line, filetype-c++

With the following command, I'd like to glob for all .cpp files so that I can compile and run simple programs:

```
autocmd FileType cpp nnoremap <buffer><silent><localleader>cr :execute '!clear; g++ ' . expand(glob('*.cpp')) . '; ./a.out<CR>
```

Right now, the expand function outputs extra characters after each file:

```
E492: Not an editor command: Account.cpp^@CreditCard.cpp^@w3_in_lab.cpp
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but you could try this autocmd:

```
autocmd FileType cpp nnoremap <buffer><silent><localleader>cr :execute '!clear; g++ ' . join(map(glob('*.cpp', 0, 1), 'shellescape(v:val, 1)')) . '; ./a.out'<CR>
```

---

If you don't pass a third argument to `glob()`, which evaluates to `TRUE`, the output is a string where the matches are separated by newline characters.

To avoid this, you could pass `1` as a third argument, so that the output is a list. Then, call `join()` to concatenate all the matches found by `glob()`.

The second argument passed to `glob()` is `0`. It means that your `'suffixes'` and `'wildignore'` options will apply during the expansion.

Also, since there could be characters inside your filenames, which have a special meaning to the shell or to Vim, you could call `map()` and `shellescape()` to protect them (passing `1`, as a 2nd argument, to the latter).

---

It's not linked to your issue, but you could move this autocmd inside a filetype plugin, for example inside `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim`, you would write something like:

```
nnoremap <buffer><silent> <key> :execute '!clear; g++ ' . join(map(glob('*.cpp', 0, 1), 'shellescape(v:val, 1)')) . '; ./a.out'<CR>
```